# gather with columns that begin with numbers

Tags: r

I have this data frame

```
 first = quantile(c(1,2,3),c(.5,.6)) 
  second = quantile(c(7,78,8),c(.5,.6)) 
  main =as.data.frame(rbind(first, second))
  main$group = cbind(  as.character(rownames(main) ) )
  main

       50%  60%  group
first    2  2.2  first
second   8 22.0 second
```

and I would like to transform it with gather but I get the error:

```
  main %>% gather(key= Percentile, value = value, c("50%","60%"))
```

> ```
> Error: All select() inputs must resolve to integer column positions.
> The following do not:
> *  c("50%", "60%")
> ```

result should be:

```
group    Percentile    value
first     50%                2
first     60%                 2.2
second    50%                8
second    60%                  22
```

thank you

Comment: `gather()` is from `tidyr` not `dplyr`

Comment: Please try my updated answer. I pasted the wrong line and you commented right as I was editing the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here it is:

```
main %>% gather(Percentile, value = value,c(`50%`, `60%`))
```

> ```
>    group Percentile value
> 1  first        50%   2.0
> 2 second        50%   8.0
> 3  first        60%   2.2
> 4 second        60%  22.0
> ```

Comment: @user3022875 What do you mean? I edited right when you commented, maybe try it again

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about `gather` but `library(reshape2)` will do what you want

```
reshape2::melt(main, id.vars = "group")

   group variable value
1  first      50%   2.0
2 second      50%   8.0
3  first      60%   2.2
4 second      60%  22.0
```

you can do it with `gather` just not with those column names you currently have. you really should never be using names with arithmetic/special characters in them.

```
colnames(main) <- c("fifty", "sixty", "group")
gather(main, key = group, value = number, fifty, sixty)

   group group number
1  first fifty    2.0
2 second fifty    8.0
3  first sixty    2.2
4 second sixty   22.0
```

Comment: I think it was apparent that you could rename the columns, but working with the special column names in gather is the heart of the question